# Titanium: window width 3 time bigger in genymotion machine

Tags: android, titanium, development-environment, genymotion

I have an app written with Titanium/Alloy and running in these environment:

1. ios simulator and devices
2. android device (old samsung with android 2.3)
3. genymotion virtual machine (android 4.x: MotoX, Galaxy 4s, etc...)

In first two cases I have no problem, but in genymotion I have this weird issues: **window canvas is set to be three times the screen, thus I have some of my app hidden**. The workaround was straight forward:

```
if(ENV_DEV && OS_ANDROID){
    $.myContentView.width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / 3;
}
```

and so I can continue developing in genymotion, but I'm still struggling for the reasons. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Thanls

Comment: The size in pixels of a Galaxy4S is most likely much much bigger than an old android device, and the iOS simulator.

Comment: Have you tried setting `<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dip</property>` in `tiapp.xml` ?

Comment: @daniula I did, with no differences

Comment: @JosiahHester the problem issues in Galaxy4S as well as in other instances like MotoX